# Unable to execute Websocket in jmeter but the same stuff is working fine in postman

Tags: jmeter, postman, performance-testing

The websocket in Postman is immediately connected below, producing a room and a socket.
wss:/service.com/?token=POTE117771

However, the outcome of the websocket added plugins in JMeter is 0"sid":"UME84d0DoF9N3tDCAABQ","upgrades":[],"pingInterval":25000,"pingTimeout":20000,"maxPayload":1000000.
However, no rooms or scokets are made.

It should be connected for jmeter to send requests. kindly assist me

Answer (score 0):

We are not telepathic enough to "assist" you without seeing your Postman and JMeter configuration, which exact plugin you're using:

- [JMeter-WebSocketSampler by Maciej Zaleski](https://github.com/fshutdown/JMeter-WebSocketSampler/wiki)
- or [JMeter WebSocket Samplers by Peter Doornbosch](https://bitbucket.org/pjtr/jmeter-websocket-samplers/src/master/)

But one thing is obvious: if you send the same request (or in case of WebSockets it might be a sequence of requests) you will get the same response so make sure that JMeter is sending the same request as Postman does (apart from dynamic parts which need to be [correlated](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/correlation-in-jmeter)) the request from JMeter will "produce room and socket" (whatever it is)